# The pronunciation of "dr-" as "jr-" by some American English speakers

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I've noticed that some Americans pronounce **dr** as **jr** , such as:

- draft → jraft
- Andrew → Anjrew

Is this standard pronunciation?

Comment: As Kosmo writes in the duplicate: “These variants don't come from Yiddish, German, or any other language. It is simply a natural phonological process that occurs in many languages, often due to co-articulatory factors.”  It also happens in words like *tree* in the unvoiced version. These are not different phonemes, merely natural allophones, and untrained native speakers are completely oblivious as to whether they do it or not (Kosmo is not untrained :). As a non-native speaker, you have to learn to hear the abstract mental phoneme, not the myriad allophones that don't matter.

Comment: Related: [What is the IPA for "trade"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146795/what-is-the-ipa-for-trade)

Comment: All I can say is that you have noticed wrong. It's simply not believable that any AmE speaker would say jraft for draft.

Comment: @Lambie   *Drafts* and *giraffes* are impossible to distinguish in many Southern dialects. *Dreary* is commonly pronounced *jreary*.

Comment: @Lambie it's entirely believable.  I once had a conversation stop in its tracks because my Greek conversation partner insisted that I stop saying "chrain" when referring to intercity rail transportation.  Or chransportation.

Comment: @Lambie I can't believe that you have never heard this from any American. How do Americans you hear pronounce "Trump"? A couple of instances I found in a quick YouTube search: In https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRmnaszQRGg Joe Biden says 1:09 "transportation". In https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61yTbx8IsCo Pete Buttigieg says 0:07 "entrusting" 0:23 "transportation".

Comment: Can someone reopen the thread? It was stupid to close it.

Comment: It's probably dumb to close this without first explaining how it relates to the other thread.

Comment: I would have said they were pronounced / ˈdɒk tər / and / ˈdʒun yər /

Comment: @phoog Remember when Dick Cheney joined the board of directors for a RR. It took about five seconds for people to start calling him Choo Choo Cheney